# python - compare two directories recursively and flag equivalent structure

Tags: python, performance, recursion

I have read many questions in stackoverflow, related to python compare directory. However, my current question is bit different.
I have two directories, which contains two different version release package contents. Now I want to compare to ensure the contents are same. **However** few files have version name embedded into them. Now which is the best possible way to compare them and conclude (except the version difference, all files match).

---

For example:
Version **V1R1C1** contains directory structure as below

```
pmt> find . -name "*"
.
./c1
./c1/c2
./c1/c1_V1R1C1.cfg
./a1
./a1/a1_V1R1C1.cfg
./a1/a2
./a1/a2/a1a2_V1R1C1.cfg
./b1/a_best_file.txt
./b1/b2/a_test_file.txt
./b1/b2/b1b2_V1R1C1.cfg
./a_V1R1C1.cfg
```

Version **V2R3C1** may contain below structure

```
pmt> find . -name "*"
.
./c1
./c1/c2
./c1/c1_V2R3C1.cfg
./a1
./a1/a1_V2R3C1.cfg
./a1/a2
./a1/a2/a1a2_V2R3C1.cfg
./b1/a_best_file.txt
./b1/b2/a_test_file.txt
./b1/b2/b1b2_V2R3C1.cfg
./a_V2R3C1.cfg
```

---

In the above case, the program must flag it as **equivalent** structure.

I can think of few solutions - like for example, read both the directory structure recursively into cache (dict), rip the version information and compare etc. But looks like not a completely effective mechanism because of two reason 1. It does not utilize the inbuilt directory compare 2.The multiple read/rip/compare is bound to cost (especially with huge directory tree structure).

I am looking for ideas, which are simple and efficient than the one above.

---

PS :
1. In case of any difference (except the version unlike the above example), I would like to use the left/right etc to get diffed list.
2. We can assume before hand which is the version name in both directories (like V1R1C1 in first case and V2R3C1 in second case).

Comment: Have you thought of just using `diff`? This is what is was designed for. There are Python implementations of diff type output as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about use set compare?

```
set((remove_version(filepath) for filepath in iter_file(dic1))) == set((remove_version(filepath) for filepath in iter_file(dic2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

the glob module has an iterator function(compared to list generation) that you could probably use in a light for loop to iterate over each file entry and then kick the differences to a separate list/dictionary.

that way you're not generating a huge batch of filenames and then picking through them.

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/glob.html#module-glob